# Elementos de tela - Android com Appium

Tags: java, junit, appium

Boa tarde, poderiam me ajudar?

estou uma semana tentando localizar um elemento de tela via AppiumInspector, mas mesmo utilizando o Xpath informado ele não encontra o elemento, quando inspeciono pelo DevTools só mostra Div, sem ID, type, ou algo que facilite a identificação

Elementos informado pelo AppiumInpesctor:

Find By  xpath

Selector:
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.view.View/android.view.View[5]

Attribute   Value
elementId   00000000-0000-082c-0000-002100000004

index   5
package br.com.cetelem.mobilebank.qa
class   android.view.View

Tela AppiumInspector no linkabaixo (não tive permissão para anexar)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a38VC.png

Tela DevTools
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJx4H.png

preciso localizar o campo senha, após clicar ele exibe o teclado virtual do próprio app, até tentei criar um xpath mas o erro é o mesmo,

[W3C] Matched W3C error code 'no such element' to NoSuchElementError
[BaseDriver] Waited for 22080 ms so far
[WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'

Muito Obrigado...